# How to pass a parameter to a built-in function's callback? (i.e. HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob)

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I would like to do checks against the resulting Blob, which requires me to pass my own variable to the callback. However, [`toBlob()` only passes the Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Parameters). How can I pass my own variable to the callback? Or, is there a better method to accomplish this that doesn't involve passing a parameter to the callback?

After trying `.bind`, I couldn't get it to work:

```
  function handleCanvas(canvas, inputImage, file, quality, resolutionMultiplier) {
    console.log(quality);
    canvas.toBlob(processImage.bind(null, inputImage, file, quality, resolutionMultiplier), "image/jpeg", Math.max(quality, 1) / 100)
  }

  function processImage(newBlob, inputImage, file, quality, resolutionMultiplier) {
    console.log(quality);
  }
```

This prints out:

```
72
0.5
```

But they should both be 72. Since `resolutionMultiplier` is 0.5, all the parameters seem to be moved over one to the left. The blob that I want from `toBlob` doesn't get passed into `processImage` at all.

FINAL EDIT: Found the solution, much more straight-forward than I thought it would be:

```
  function handleCanvas(canvas, inputImage, file, quality, resolutionMultiplier) {
    canvas.toBlob(function (newBlob) {
      processImage(newBlob, inputImage, file, quality, resolutionMultiplier);
    }, "image/jpeg", Math.max(quality, 1) / 100)
  }
```

Comment: How are you using `toBlob()`? What is the other variable?

Comment: I guess that depends? Do you want it to be just a polyfill, it looks that way from the first condition, and if so, shouldn't it be consistent with the native method you're polyfilling? If you want to check something, just do it inside the callback ?

Comment: @MattWay The other variable is the filesize of the original jpeg. I use it to compare if the Blob is smaller or not.

Comment: @adeneo It must be consistent with the native method. If not, then this would be so much simpler. How can I know which variable to check it against in the callback if I don't pass in some reference value like a uuid?

Comment: Please add some code showing how you try to use toBlob, including your filesize variable. Or how you would like it to work.

Comment: @MattWay I've added some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use case isn't entirely clear from your question, but in general you'd simply pass the custom variable through a closure:

```
var oldSize = ...;

function callback(blob) {
    if (blob.size < oldSize) {
        // take appropriate action
    }
}

canvas.toBlob(callback);
```

An alternative might be to bind the `oldSize` as an argument:

```
function callback(oldSize, blob) {
    // ...
}

var oldSize = ...;

canvas.toBlob(callback.bind(null, oldSize));
```

Comment: Hey, sorry to [temporarily] take back the checkmark, but `.bind` isn't working when I use it this way. I've updated the original question with details, could you please take a look?

Comment: You were expecting `bind` to bind arguments to the end of the argument list. It binds to the beginning of the argument list instead, so the `newBlob` needs to be the *last* argument to the function. See my example above.

Answer (score 0):

you callback is passing only the new Blob.

```
callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ) )
```

change to

```
callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ), your_value )
```

Comment: But I cannot change the native function of browsers unfortunately.